# How to open pdf from server from Android app in Adobe Reader

Tags: java, android, pdf, adobe-reader

I'm trying to open a pdf file from a server in adobe reader.  These are valid pdfs that I can view in other apps.  The following code gives me a message saying "The document could not be opened"
Any ideas why?

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(documents.get(position).getPdf_url()), "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can the Adobe Reader app display documents from URL's without downloading them first?

Comment: Agreed, usually PDF viewers are working with local files. Also, please allow the user to choose their PDF viewer.

Comment: can you refer me to an explanation of how to download the pdf to local storage?

Comment: You can use the [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to download the pdf files to local memory before opening in an external app.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(doc), "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Above code is working for me, There are two possibilities, may be you need to set package with intent only or you are doing something wrong with doc URI.